# jquery animation with no duration

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-animate, duration

I'm trying to access the values of a jQuery animation without setting a duration. (but need the duration property to tell the animation how many steps I want to have). Actually I dont't want to animate anything, I just want jQuery to calculate the values between min and max. The reason why I dont't calculate them myself is that I want to make use of jQuery's easings and those of the jQuery Easing Plugin

```
var min = 0,
    max = 50,
    steps = 20,
    values_arr = [];

$({value: min}).animate({value: max}, {
    duration: steps, 
    step: function (v) {values_arr.push(v)}
})
```

Is there any way not to wait for the animation but get all the values instantly?

Comment: what are you trying to accomplish when you say "calculate the values between min and max"

Comment: I want to use it for a paper.js script where the values will influence some vectors. But in general I think it would be very handy to use jQuery to calculate values but use them outside the animation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can call the ease functions directly like this :

```
$.easing.easeInQuad(null, elapsedTime, initialValue, changeAmount, duration);
```

Just change elapsedTime from 0 to duration to get the values you need. Notice that you pass the amount of change, not the destination value.

With your data, you could do something like this:

```
var min = 0,
    max = 50,
    steps = 20,
    values_arr = [];


for(var i = 0; i < steps; i++){
    values_arr.push($.easing.easeInQuad(null, i, min, max, steps));
}
```